# Update statement to set a column based the maximum row of another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, h2

I have a `Family` table:

```
SELECT * FROM Family;

id | Surname  | Oldest | Oldest_Age    
---+----------+--------+-------
 1 | Byre     | NULL   | NULL
 2 | Summers  | NULL   | NULL
 3 | White    | NULL   | NULL
 4 | Anders   | NULL   | NULL
```

The `Family.Oldest` column is not yet populated. There is another table of `Children`:

```
SELECT * FROM Children;

id | Name     | Age  | Family_FK
---+----------+------+--------
 1 | Jake     | 8    | 1
 2 | Martin   | 7    | 2
 3 | Sarah    | 10   | 1
 4 | Tracy    | 12   | 3
```

where many children (or no children) can be associated with one family. I would like to populate the `Oldest` column using an `UPDATE ... SET ...` statement that sets it to the `Name` and `Oldest_Age` of the oldest child in each family. Finding the name of each oldest child is a problem that is solved quite well here: [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

However, I don't know how to use the result of this in an `UPDATE` statement to update the column of an associated table using the `h2` database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is ANSI-SQL syntax that solves this problem:

```
update family
    set oldest = (select name
                  from children c
                  where c.family_fk = f.id
                  order by age desc
                  fetch first 1 row only
                 )
```

In h2, I think you would use `limit 1` instead of `fetch first 1 row only`.

EDIT:

For two columns -- alas -- the solution is two subqueries:

```
update family
    set oldest = (select name
                  from children c
                  where c.family_fk = f.id
                  order by age desc
                  limit 1
                 ),
        oldest_age = (select age
                      from children c
                      where c.family_fk = f.id
                      order by age desc
                      limit 1
                     );
```

Some databases (such as SQL Server, Postgres, and Oracle) support lateral joins that can help with this.  Also, `row_number()` can also help solve this problem.  Unfortunately, H2 doesn't support this functionality.

Comment: Thanks, that looks surprisingly simple! Do you also know how I would go about updating two columns using the same subquery? I added an `Oldest_Age` column to my example that I totally forgot about.